# Regex parse multiple separate words and ignore double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I'm trying to parse a string similar to the one below.  This represents queries for a book.  Multiple options are available to look for specific fields, so `intitle:` looks for something in the title of the book specifically.  I have two problems.

1. It's not parsing out some of the terms in the third returned element such as inauthor and inpublisher -  'champ inauthor:"john smith" inpublisher:"the book place" ' - this may have something to do with the double quotes in the string?
2. How can I use the double quotes to make it a single term?

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mateoc15/jwsmufog/3/)

The string:

```
basketball intitle:champ inauthor:"john smith" inpublisher:"the book place" subject: fiba isbn: 12345 lccn: 689778 oclc: 1234156
```

My attempt

```
let q: string = `basketball intitle:champ inauthor:"john smith" inpublisher:"the book place" subject: fiba isbn: 12345 lccn: 689778 oclc: 1234156`;
console.log(q);
q = q.replaceAll(`: `, `:`);
console.log(q);
let all = q.split(
  /(\bintitle:\b|\binauthor:\b|\binpublisher:\b|\bsubject:\b|\bisbn:\b|\blccn:\b|\boclc:\b)/,
);
console.log(all);
```

```
[
  'basketball ',
  'intitle:',
  'champ inauthor:"john smith" inpublisher:"the book place" ',
  'subject:',
  'fiba ',
  'isbn:',
  '12345 ',
  'lccn:',
  '689778 ',
  'oclc:',
  '1234156'
]
```

Comment: There is no [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) in between `:` and `"`. Something like `:\b` can only match a colon that is followed by a [word character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) (letter, digit, underscore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments `:\b` will not match `:"` as there is no word break after the colon.

I would suggest using `matchAll` and explicitly match the part in quotes. For instance:

```js
const q = `basketball intitle:champ inauthor:"john smith" inpublisher:"the book place" subject: fiba isbn: 12345 lccn: 689778 oclc: 1234156`;

const matches = q.matchAll(/\s*(?:(\w+):\s*)?(?:"([^"]+)"|(\S+))/g);
const obj = Object.fromEntries(
    Array.from(matches, ([, key, val1, val2]) => [key ?? "__main", val1 ?? val2])
);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use adaptive word boundaries here if the search words can start/end with different characters in them:

```js
let q: string = `basketball intitle:champ inauthor:"john smith" inpublisher:"the book place" subject: fiba isbn: 12345 lccn: 689778 oclc: 1234156`;
q = q.replaceAll(`: `, `:`);

let terms = ['intitle:', 'inauthor:', 'inpublisher:', 'subject:', 'isbn:', 'lccn:', 'oclc:'];
let regex: RegExp = new RegExp(String.raw`(?!\B\w)(${terms.map(x => x.replace(/[\/\-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join('|')})(?!\B\w)`);

let all = q.split(regex);
console.log(all);
```

The regex will look like

```
/(?!\B\w)(intitle:|inauthor:|inpublisher:|subject:|isbn:|lccn:|oclc:)(?!\B\w)/
```

where `(?!\B\w)` will only require a word boundary if the characters at the start / end of the "word" are word characters.

The `terms.map(x => x.replace(/[\/\-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join('|')` part escapes the search `terms` in case there are any special regex metacharacters.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution not using regex is to first split the string on `:`, then split each of the parts on  , knowing that (other than for the last part) each part consists of a value followed by a one-word key. So we slice off the key and join the value parts back together before pushing to the output array:

```js
let q = `basketball intitle:champ inauthor:"john smith" inpublisher:"the book place" subject: fiba isbn: 12345 lccn: 689778 oclc: 1234156`;

let parts = q.split(/\s*:\s*/)

let all = parts.slice(0,-1).reduce((acc, s) => {
  const words = s.split(' ')
  const len = words.length
  return acc.concat([words.slice(0, -1).join(' '), words[len-1]])
}, []).concat(parts.slice(-1))

console.log(all)
```

Note if you want the `:` on the end of the keys, just change `words[len-1]` to `words[len-1] + ':'` in the `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split with a RegExp to get your array of keys and values.

In a second step you can clean up the keys and values and put them in a `map:Record<string,string>`.

```js
let q = `basketball intitle:champ inauthor:"john smith" inpublisher:"the book place" subject: fiba isbn: 12345 lccn: 689778 oclc: 1234156`;

const arr = q.split(/\s+(\S+\s*:)\s*/g);
console.log(arr);

const map = {};
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  const key = arr[i].replace(/\s*:/, "");
  const value = arr[i + 1];
  
  map[key] = (value.startsWith('"') && value.endsWith('"')) ? 
    value.slice(1, -1) : 
    value;
}

console.log(arr[0], map);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```